# Can the Complete Graph on ten vertices be edge covered by three copies of the Petersen Graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Put another way ... Colour the edges of the complete graph with 3 colours, so that three subgraphs are each a copy of the Petersen Graph.
I heard somewhere that it can be done (Maybe I should not go on MathOverFlow !) but I have spent all weekend trying and have convinced myself it is impossible. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question!

Answer (score 7):

[Section 1.5.1 in *Spectra of Graphs*](http://books.google.com/books?id=F98THwYgrXYC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=decomposing+the+complete+graph+into+petersen+graphs&source=bl&ots=ge0gubv4IS&sig=W4kdUU8H8idpQ3jttuzkZIeVxLo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lSSxT7T9Fuj10gGZ4cH4Cw&ved=0CFgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Brouwer and Haemers says that there is no such decomposition. ([Downloadable PDF here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/math/ipm/ipm.pdf))

I am not going to pretend to understand the proof, but it is at the very beginning of the book, so it might be possible to read just a little bit and understand what is going on.

I found this result cited in a couple of places as a surprising application of linear algebra to graph theory.

Addendum: [Here's another, possibly more readable description of the same technique](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2011/spectral_GT/MC2011_spectral_GT_wk4_day1.pdf). (PDF)

Addendum: However, [this page says that you *can* partition a double $K_{10}$ into *six* Petersen graphs](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/regs/idecsrg.html)!

Comment: Thanks for putting me out of my misery ! so the answer is negative, confirming my convoluted arguement (that only exists in my mind) is probably correct.
Ive just heard that K16 can covered by 3 copies of the Clebsch Graph! Mark: 6 copies of P10 will do 2 copies of K10 will it ?
Kindest Regards Herman

Comment: Not exactly. A "double $K_{10}$" is not two disjoint copies of $K_{10}$, which would have 20 vertices and 90 edges.  Rather, it is the graph you get by taking $K_{10}$ and replacing each single edge with two edges; it has 10 vertices and 90 edges.  This "double" graph can be decomposed into six Petersen graphs.  Two disjoint $K_{10}$s clearly can't, since that would imply a decomposition of either component separately.

Comment: You're welcome!  Don't forget to "accept" one of the answers.  You may also be interested to see *[Decomposing the Higman-Sims graph into double Petersen graphs](http://math.fau.edu/~npace/data/ivanicmag.pdf)*. (PDF)  The Higman-Sims graph has 100 vertices and 1100 edges.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of impossibility is also given in [Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical and Algorithmic Applications of Linear Algebra](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/19/?pa=reviews&sa=viewBook&bookId=71276), specifically Minature 13, "Three Petersens are not enough".  I was able to view a substantial portion of this as a Google Books result.

Answer (score 2):

This can be checked computationally.  Here is my [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
F:=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[1,5],[6,8],[8,10],[7,10],[7,9],[6,9],[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]];
```

In the above, `F` is the edge set of the Petersen graph.

```
count:=0;
S:=[];
for alpha in SymmetricGroup(10) do
  F2:=OnSetsSets(F,alpha);
  count:=count+1;
  if(Intersection(F,F2)=[]) then
    S:=Concatenation(S,[F2]);
    Print(Size(S)," out of ",count," out of ",Factorial(10),"; expecting: ",1.0*Factorial(10)*Size(S)/count,"\n");
  fi;
od;
```

The above generates a list `S` of graphs isomorphic to the Petersen graph `F` which do not share an edge.

```
B:=[S[1],S[1]];
best:=Size(Intersection(B[1],B[2]));
for i in [1..Size(S)] do
  for j in [i+1..Size(S)] do
    F1:=S[i];
    F2:=S[j];
    int:=Size(Intersection(F1,F2));
    if(int<best) then
      best:=int;
      B:=[F1,F2];
      Print("Best thus far: ",best,"\n",B[1],"\n",B[2],"\n\n");
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

The above attempts to find two members of `S`, denoted `F1` and `F2`, which are edge disjoint.  It doesn't find any.  The best it finds is the following:

[image: The graphs isomorphic to the Petersen graph; the last two share 6 edges.]

Here the last two graphs share the 6 edges highlighted in bold.